# Updating one value in dictionary updates every value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following function, which does extracts some data and then tries to store each data in its respective location in the dictionary `tickerdata`. Each value of the dictionary is another dictionary. However, the values for the first inner dictionary(key = "MMM") are being set as the values for the rest of the dictionary. I am uncertain on how to fix this.

```
def scandata(volumelimita, volumelimitb, lastchangelimita,lastchangelimitb, ivlimita, ivlimitb):
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    tickerdata = {key: {} for key in tickers}
    keydefine = {"price":0, "volume":0, "netchange":0, "iv":0}
    tickerdata = {key: keydefine for key in tickers}
    for i in range(100):
        #print("increment is "+str(i))
        stock = tickers[i]
        try:
            if((fetchstock(stock)['totalVolume']>volumelimita) and (fetchstock(stock)['totalVolume']< volumelimitb) and (fetchstock(stock)['netChange']>lastchangelimita) and (fetchstock(stock)['netChange']< lastchangelimitb) and((fetchstock(stock)['volatility']*100)>ivlimita)and((fetchstock(stock)['volatility']*100)<ivlimitb)):
                tickerdata[stock]['price'] = fetchstock(stock)[stock]['lastPrice']
                tickerdata[stock]['volume'] = fetchstock(stock)[stock]['totalVolume']
                tickerdata[stock]['netchange']= fetchstock(stock)[stock]['netChange']
                tickerdata[stock]['iv'] = fetchstock(stock)[stock]['volatility']*100
        except KeyError:
            print('here was a key error at '+ stock)
            pass
    return tickerdata
```

Output:

```
here was a key error at AKAM
here was a key error at ALK
here was a key error at ALB
here was a key error at ARE
here was a key error at ALXN
here was a key error at ALGN
here was a key error at ALLE
here was a key error at LNT
here was a key error at ALL
here was a key error at GOOGL
here was a key error at GOOG
here was a key error at MO
here was a key error at AMZN
here was a key error at AMCR
here was a key error at AEE
here was a key error at AAL
here was a key error at AEP
here was a key error at AXP
here was a key error at AIG
here was a key error at AMT
here was a key error at AWK
here was a key error at AMP
here was a key error at ABC
here was a key error at AME
here was a key error at AMGN
here was a key error at APH
here was a key error at ADI
here was a key error at ANSS
here was a key error at ANTM
here was a key error at AON
here was a key error at AOS
here was a key error at APA
here was a key error at AIV
here was a key error at AAPL
here was a key error at AMAT
here was a key error at APTV
here was a key error at ADM
here was a key error at ANET
here was a key error at AJG
here was a key error at AIZ
here was a key error at T
here was a key error at ATO
here was a key error at ADSK
here was a key error at ADP
here was a key error at AZO
here was a key error at AVB
here was a key error at AVY
here was a key error at BKR
here was a key error at BLL
here was a key error at BAC
here was a key error at BK
here was a key error at BAX
here was a key error at BDX
here was a key error at BRK.B
here was a key error at BBY
here was a key error at BIO
here was a key error at BIIB
here was a key error at BLK
here was a key error at BA
here was a key error at BKNG
here was a key error at BWA
here was a key error at BXP
here was a key error at BSX
here was a key error at BMY
here was a key error at AVGO
here was a key error at BR
here was a key error at CBRE
here was a key error at CDW
here was a key error at CE
here was a key error at CNC
here was a key error at CNP
here was a key error at CERN
here was a key error at CF
here was a key error at SCHW
{'MMM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ABT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ABBV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ABMD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ACN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ATVI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ADBE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AAP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AES': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AFL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'A': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'APD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AKAM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ARE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALXN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALGN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALLE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'LNT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ALL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'GOOGL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'GOOG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'MO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMZN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMCR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AEE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AAL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AEP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AXP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AIG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AWK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ABC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AME': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMGN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'APH': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ADI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ANSS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ANTM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AON': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AOS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'APA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AIV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AAPL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AMAT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'APTV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ADM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ANET': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AJG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AIZ': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'T': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ATO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ADSK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ADP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AZO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AVB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AVY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BKR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BLL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BAC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BAX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BDX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BRK.B': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BBY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BIO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BIIB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BLK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BKNG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BWA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BXP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BSX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BMY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'AVGO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'BF.B': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CHRW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'COG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CDNS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CPB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'COF': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CAH': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'KMX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CCL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CARR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CTLT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CAT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CBOE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CBRE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CDW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CNC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CNP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CERN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CF': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'SCHW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CHTR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CVX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CMG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CHD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CINF': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CTAS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CSCO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'C': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CFG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CTXS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CLX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CME': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CMS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'KO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CTSH': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CMCSA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CMA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CAG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CXO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'COP': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ED': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'STZ': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'COO': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CPRT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'GLW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CTVA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'COST': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CCI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CSX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CMI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'CVS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DHI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DHR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DRI': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DVA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DAL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'XRAY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DVN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DXCM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FANG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DLR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DFS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DISCA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DISCK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DISH': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DLTR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'D': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DPZ': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DOV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DOW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DTE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DUK': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DRE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'DXC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EMN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ETN': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EBAY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ECL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EIX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EW': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EA': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EMR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ETR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EOG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EFX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EQIX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EQR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ESS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EL': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ETSY': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EVRG': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'ES': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'RE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EXC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EXPE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EXPD': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'EXR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'XOM': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FFIV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FAST': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FRT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FDX': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FIS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FITB': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FE': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FRC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FISV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FLT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FLIR': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FLS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FMC': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'F': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FTNT': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FTV': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589, 'netchange': 0.0, 'iv': 4.78}, 'FBHS': {'price': 85.97, 'volume': 990589..
```

Comment: You already got an answer but why do you use `tickerdata = {key: {} for key in tickers}`? There is no need to initialise the dict; that's a hang-up from another language

Comment: For that, you might use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: @roganjosh i see what you're saying now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
keydefine = {"price":0, "volume":0, "netchange":0, "iv":0}
tickerdata = {key: keydefine for key in tickers}
```

This uses a reference to the same `dict` object for every value in `tickerdata`. See with `id`:

```
print([id(val) for val in tickerdata.values()])
# [13068360, 13068360]
```

Either use `keydefine.copy()` or create a new `dict` directly:

```
tickerdata = {key: keydefine.copy() for key in tickers}
```

or

```
tickerdata = {key: {"price": 0, "volume": 0, "netchange": 0, "iv": 0} for key in tickers}
```

Or as @roganjosh noted in the comments, you don't even have to initialize the inner `dict` with values:

```
tickerdata = {key: {} for key in tickers}
```

At this point you can simply do

```
tickerdata  = dict.fromkeys(tickers, {})
```

Comment: `copy()` worked like a charm. I was not aware of this characteristic of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be `fetchstock(stock)[stock]`.  In if statements you just use `fetchstock(stock)` to be a dict.   Recommend the following changes so you can see what key is failing?

```
def scandata(volumelimita, volumelimitb, lastchangelimita,lastchangelimitb, ivlimita, ivlimitb):
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    keydefine = {"price":0, "volume":0, "netchange":0, "iv":0}
    tickerdata = {key: keydefine for key in tickers}
    for stock in tickers[0:100]
        try:
            k = None
            s = fetchstock(stock)
            k = 'totalVolume'
            if not (s[k]>volumelimita): continue 
            if not (s[k]< volumelimitb): continue

            k = 'netChange'
            if not (s[k]>lastchangelimita): continue
            if not (s[k]< lastchangelimitb): continue

            k = 'volatility'
            volatility = s[k]*100
            if not (volatility>ivlimita): continue
            if not ((volatility<ivlimitb): continue

            t = tickerdata[stock]

            t['iv']       = volatility

            k = 'lastPrice'
            t['price']    = s[k]

            k = 'totalVolume'
            t['volume']   = s[k]

            k = 'netChange'
            t['netchange']= s[]


        except KeyError:
            print('here was a key error at '+ stock, k)
            pass
    return tickerdata
```